# How to switch back to origin app after using storybook react native

Tags: react-native, storybook

I had a react native app. I applied storybook by using `getstorybook` from official doc.

Every times I run `react-native run-ios`, the app is the storybook, not my app anymore. Now I don't know how to switch back my original app.

I tried to close all my terminals + remove build folder but no one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

- storybook for react native use `React Packager` of react native to bundle the stories.
- because the `Packager` was used for storybook, it could not be used for app.
- to fix this, just close all process related to storybook first
- then run `npm run start` or `yarn start` to make `Packager` used for the app.
- then run `react-native run-ios/android` will get the app back.